# Ошибка с MemoryMappedFile (NotSupportedException) .net core при использовании под linux?

Tags: c#, linux

Доброе времени суток. Возникла необходимость делиться информацией между двумя приложениями. Вспомнил что есть `MemoryMappedFile`, решил воспользоваться. Зашел msdn глянул работает и под **.net core** - что очень важно. Так как рассматривается вариант запуска **сервисов под linux-ом**. Но тут же я столкнулся с проблемой под linux-ом:

> "Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Named maps
>   are not supported."

*Вопрос все еще актуален*
**Есть ли какие-то *альтернативы*? Как вы решаете проблему с обработкой больших объемов, что бы они были доступны между двух и более сервисов?**

Задача: 
есть данные примерно такого вида:
`id price1 price1` (*таких записей 1млн*) которые необходимо обновлять, ну скажем раз 20 в секунду

UPDATE#1

Named maps - это функция, предоставляемая Windows. Как правило, отображаемые в память файлы работают путем межпроцессного взаимодействия, отображая один и тот же файл в несколько процессов, например, используя MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile.

Если не использовать именование, то запись будет иметь такой вид:

```
string path = "/home/test/test";
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fs, null, fs.Length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, HandleInheritability.None, true))
using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor acc = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
```

Comment: [Creating MemoryMappedFile fails with PlatformNotSupportedException](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20091)

Comment: возьмите любой key-value storage, тот же redis

Comment: Редиска или Касандра подойдут идеально.

Answer (score 1):

Именованные memory mapped файлы под Linux не поддерживаются.

Альтернатива - готовые key-value storage. IMO, проще всего будет прикрутить [Redis](https://redis.io/). Есть [готовый образ на dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis)  + есть хороший [.NET клиент от Stack Exchange](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis)